# Views - Separating multi-value fields into rows

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views, drupal-panels

I'm creating a view for a production site and I've run into a bit of a problem.

What I'm dealing with is a a fieldset, and a multiple fields container nested inside. Within there are three different values:

1. Cheque amount
2. Cheque date
3. Cheque number

Fine and dandy - the user can go in, add one and if they need another they can add a new row and go from there. Now this is the issue. This puts items into the database together. If there are multiple Cheque amounts they go in like:

- Amount: 1000, 2000, etc.
- Date: 2006, 2007, etc.
- Number: 1, 2, etc.

So by default they display under one header, below each other. Okay that's fine and all.. but now I make a view so it's more readable. The issue that I'm having is simple - I want everything to display in a table. So I switch it to table and I turn the option to put everything on a single line off. I get for a result not TWO records but 8. Every combination is a record.

- 1000,2006,1
- 1000,2007,1
- 1000,2006,2
- 1000,2007,2
- 2000,2006,1
- 2000,2007,1
- 2000,2006,2
- 2000,2007,2

What do I do to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

by using field tpl you can create  logic
in theme information you can take field tpl name.